# How to get the value from XML in SQL

Tags: sql, xml

I could not find an error. Select s empty, but should be not...

```
declare @xml xml =
'<ArrayOfFinancialDecimalKeyValue xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Quipu.CRMExtensions.BusinessLogicLayer.Financials.Models.Financials">
  <FinancialDecimalKeyValue>
    <ReferenceCode>fx_risk_lt_st_liabilities_currency3_realistic_percentage_input</ReferenceCode>
    <Value>5</Value>
    <AttributeName>fx_risk_lt_st_liabilities_currency3_realistic_percentage</AttributeName>
    <Type1>realistic_percentage</Type1>
    <Type2>currency3</Type2>
    <IsDivByZero i:nil="true" />
  </FinancialDecimalKeyValue>
  <FinancialDecimalKeyValue>
    <ReferenceCode>fx_risk_lt_st_liabilities_currency3_realistic2ndYear_percentage_input</ReferenceCode>
    <Value>5</Value>
    <AttributeName>fx_risk_lt_st_liabilities_currency3_realistic2ndYear_percentage</AttributeName>
    <Type1>realistic2ndYear_percentage</Type1>
    <Type2>currency3</Type2>
    <IsDivByZero i:nil="true" />
  </FinancialDecimalKeyValue>
</ArrayOfFinancialDecimalKeyValue>'

SELECT  

       _xml.col.value('(ReferenceCode)[1]','varchar(150)') as [ReferenceCode],
       _xml.col.value('(Value)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Value],
       _xml.col.value('(AttributeName)[1]','varchar(50)') as [BalanceSheetExchangeRate],
       _xml.col.value('(Type1)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Type1]  ,
       _xml.col.value('(Type2)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Type2],
       _xml.col.value('(IsDivByZero)[1]','varchar(50)') as [IsDivByZero]            


FROM   @xml.nodes('//FinancialDecimalKeyValue') as _xml(col)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is using a default namespace. There are several ways to deal with it, but the easiest was [to use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-2017):

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Quipu.CRMExtensions.BusinessLogicLayer.Financials.Models.Financials')
SELECT  

       _xml.col.value('(ReferenceCode)[1]','varchar(150)') as [ReferenceCode],
       _xml.col.value('(Value)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Value],
       _xml.col.value('(AttributeName)[1]','varchar(50)') as [BalanceSheetExchangeRate],
       _xml.col.value('(Type1)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Type1]  ,
       _xml.col.value('(Type2)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Type2],
       _xml.col.value('(IsDivByZero)[1]','varchar(50)') as [IsDivByZero]            
FROM   @xml.nodes('//FinancialDecimalKeyValue') as _xml(col);
```

This returns

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| ReferenceCode                                                         | Value | BalanceSheetExchangeRate                           | Type1                       | Type2     | IsDivByZero |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| fx_risk_lt_st_liabilities_currency3_realistic_percentage_input        | 5     | fx_risk_lt_st_liabilities_currency3_realistic_perc | realistic_percentage        | currency3 |             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| fx_risk_lt_st_liabilities_currency3_realistic2ndYear_percentage_input | 5     | fx_risk_lt_st_liabilities_currency3_realistic2ndYe | realistic2ndYear_percentage | currency3 |             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

### UPDATE

Your comments are not really clear for me... I get, that you try to use `XMLNAMESPACES` like you'd use a CTE. Well, if you need a CTE you can do this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Quipu.CRMExtensions.BusinessLogicLayer.Financials.Models.Financials')
,CTE AS
(
    SELECT  

           _xml.col.value('(ReferenceCode)[1]','varchar(150)') as [ReferenceCode],
           _xml.col.value('(Value)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Value],
           _xml.col.value('(AttributeName)[1]','varchar(50)') as [BalanceSheetExchangeRate],
           _xml.col.value('(Type1)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Type1]  ,
           _xml.col.value('(Type2)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Type2],
           _xml.col.value('(IsDivByZero)[1]','varchar(50)') as [IsDivByZero]            
    FROM   @xml.nodes('//FinancialDecimalKeyValue') as _xml(col)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

But I think, it's this what you are looking for:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Quipu.CRMExtensions.BusinessLogicLayer.Financials.Models.Financials')
SELECT _xml.col.value('(Value)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Value]
FROM   @xml.nodes('//FinancialDecimalKeyValue') as _xml(col)
WHERE _xml.col.value('(Type1)[1]','varchar(50)')='realistic_percentage' 
  AND _xml.col.value('(ReferenceCode)[1]','varchar(150)')='fx_risk_lt_st_liabilities_currency3_realistic_percentage_input'
```

This would return just the value "5".

Better in performance was this:

```
DECLARE @code VARCHAR(100)='fx_risk_lt_st_liabilities_currency3_realistic_percentage_input';
DECLARE @type1 VARCHAR(100)='realistic_percentage';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Quipu.CRMExtensions.BusinessLogicLayer.Financials.Models.Financials')
SELECT @xml.value('(/ArrayOfFinancialDecimalKeyValue
                    /FinancialDecimalKeyValue[(ReferenceCode/text())[1]=sql:variable("@code") and (Type1/text())[1]=sql:variable("@type1")]
                    /Value/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as [Value];
```

The last one you read as: Dive into `<ArrayOfFinancialDecimalKeyValue>`. Then look for an element `<FinancialDecimalKeyValue>`, which fullfills the *XQuery predicate* and return its `<Value>`.

### UPDATE 2

Might be, that you just got the syntax of `INSERT INTO` wrong?

Try this

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(ReferenceCode VARCHAR(150),[Value] VARCHAR(50),BalanceSheetExchangeRate VARCHAR(50),Type1 VARCHAR(50),Type2 VARCHAR(50),IsDivByzero VARCHAR(50));

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Quipu.CRMExtensions.BusinessLogicLayer.Financials.Models.Financials')
INSERT INTO @TempTable(ReferenceCode,[Value],BalanceSheetExchangeRate,Type1,Type2,IsDivByzero)
SELECT _xml.col.value('(ReferenceCode)[1]','varchar(150)') as [ReferenceCode],
       _xml.col.value('(Value)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Value],
       _xml.col.value('(AttributeName)[1]','varchar(50)') as [BalanceSheetExchangeRate],
       _xml.col.value('(Type1)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Type1]  ,
       _xml.col.value('(Type2)[1]','varchar(50)') as [Type2],
       _xml.col.value('(IsDivByZero)[1]','varchar(50)') as [IsDivByZero]            
FROM   @xml.nodes('//FinancialDecimalKeyValue') as _xml(col);

SELECT * FROM @TempTable;
```

Comment: But how then I can in the SP access the value? I need select Value from XMLNAMESPACES where Type1 = 'realistic' and ReferenceCode = 'balancesheet_long_term_loans_banks_pcb_realistic_input'. And it is not working...

Comment: It is working great, I just need to use output as a table and select a value from the XMLNAMESPACES. If I use it directly as a table SP is giving me the error "Invalid object name 'XMLNAMESPACES'"

Comment: @Erlica I don't really get it... The `XMLNAMESPACES` is not like a CTE you would want to use in a FROM or JOIN later on... The query - as stated above - returns a table... So what do you need actually? Please add details to your question using the edit option.

Comment: I need to use it as cte, as a table and make a select with certain conditions. How I can convert it to the normal table? As a result I need only one value from that table matching criteria  -- select [Value] from XMLNAMESPACES where [Type1] = 'realistic' and [ReferenceCode] = 'balancesheet_long_term_loans_banks_pcb_realistic_input'

Comment: I was trying to use temp table like INSERT INTO @TempTable
 SELECT [ReferenceCode],
 [Value],
 [AttributeName],
 [Type1],
 [Type2]
 FROM XMLNAMESPACES
but getting an error Invalid object name 'XMLNAMESPACES'.....

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Erlica Your initial question does not show, that you want to insert the result into a table. Please try to mention all important issues to the question. Nobody wants to read through tons of comments... See my UPDATE 2

Comment: @Erlica, if this solved your issue, please close this question by clicking the acceptance check below the answer's vote counter. Happy Coding!